# Parfor for Python

Tags: python, matlab, parallel-processing

I am looking for a definitive answer to MATLAB's parfor for Python (Scipy, Numpy).

Is there a solution similar to parfor? If not, what is the complication for creating one?

UPDATE: Here is a typical numerical computation code that I need speeding up

```
import numpy as np

N = 2000
output = np.zeros([N,N])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        output[i,j] = HeavyComputationThatIsThreadSafe(i,j)
```

An example of a heavy computation function is:

```
import scipy.optimize

def HeavyComputationThatIsThreadSafe(i,j):
    n = i * j

    return scipy.optimize.anneal(lambda x: np.sum((x-np.arange(n)**2)), np.random.random((n,1)))[0][0,0]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many Python frameworks for parallel computing. One option is [IPython Parallel](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). In IPython Parallel, an analogue to parfor is [`ipyparallel.DirectView.map()`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ipyparallel.html#ipyparallel.DirectView.map). See the linked documentation for details.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about client.MultiEngineClient even though I do use IPython. Thanks for the steer!

Comment: It is not apparent to me whether I can run a code sped up with IPython parallel computing framework in script mode, i.e. not running through ipython.

Comment: @Dat Chu:  Of course you can.  Just write the commands you would type at the prompt in a file an run it with Python.  (Is this what you are asking for?)

Comment: Up-to-date link to [the documentation on quick and easy parallelism](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html#quick-and-easy-parallelism).

Comment: Sven, I think you mean parfor where you write matfor.

Comment: Actually that is where the pain come from. There are too many of them and none of them suit for all propose. And you need to try out which works and which doesn't yourself. And which is faster in which case. Sometimes some implementation will be even slower than no parallel.

Comment: @River Yes, optimising code is tedious, and parallelism is hard. I suggest you start with multiprocessing, which is part of the standard library.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. You should look here now: https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @SamOT Thanks! I updated the answer with links to the newer package.

Comment: Thanks, @SvenMarnach, for the quick update! Thanks for this helpful answer, it's nice to have something that works well with IPython :)

Answer (score 31):

The one built-in to python would be `multiprocessing` docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).  I always use `multiprocessing.Pool` with as many workers as processors.  Then whenever I need to do a for-loop like structure I use `Pool.imap`

As long as the body of your function does not depend on any previous iteration then you should have near linear speed-up.  This also requires that your inputs and outputs are `pickle`-able but this is pretty easy to ensure for standard types.

UPDATE:
Some code for your updated function just to show how easy it is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product

output = np.zeros((N,N))
pool = Pool() #defaults to number of available CPU's
chunksize = 20 #this may take some guessing ... take a look at the docs to decide
for ind, res in enumerate(pool.imap(Fun, product(xrange(N), xrange(N))), chunksize):
    output.flat[ind] = res
```

Comment: You should replace `output[ind]` by `output.flat[ind]` to make the code work.  (`output` is a two-dimensional array and would need two indices.)

Comment: @Sven: Thanks ... that comes from switching between matlab and python all the time.

Answer (score 11):

## Jupyter Notebook

To see an example consider you want to write the equivalence of this Matlab code on in Python

```
matlabpool open 4
parfor n=0:9
   for i=1:10000
       for j=1:10000
           s=j*i   
       end
   end
   n
end
disp('done')
```

The way one may write this in python particularly in jupyter notebook. You have to create a function in the working directory (I called it FunForParFor.py) which has the following

```
def func(n):
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            s=j*i
    print(n)
```

Then I go to my Jupyter notebook and write the following code

```
import multiprocessing  
import FunForParFor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(FunForParFor.func, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()   
    print('done')
```

This has worked for me! I just wanted to share it here to give you a particular example.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done elegantly with [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), a system that allows you to easily parallelize and distribute your Python code.

To parallelize your example, you'd need to define your functions with the `@ray.remote` decorator, and then invoke them with `.remote`.

```
import numpy as np
import time

import ray

ray.init()

# Define the function. Each remote function will be executed 
# in a separate process.
@ray.remote
def HeavyComputationThatIsThreadSafe(i, j):
    n = i*j
    time.sleep(0.5) # Simulate some heavy computation. 
    return n

N = 10
output_ids = []
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        # Remote functions return a future, i.e, an identifier to the 
        # result, rather than the result itself. This allows invoking
        # the next remote function before the previous finished, which
        # leads to the remote functions being executed in parallel.
        output_ids.append(HeavyComputationThatIsThreadSafe.remote(i,j))

# Get results when ready.
output_list = ray.get(output_ids)
# Move results into an NxN numpy array.
outputs = np.array(output_list).reshape(N, N)

# This program should take approximately N*N*0.5s/p, where
# p is the number of cores on your machine, N*N
# is the number of times we invoke the remote function,
# and 0.5s is the time it takes to execute one instance
# of the remote function. For example, for two cores this
# program will take approximately 25sec.
```

There are a number of advantages of using Ray over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. In particular, the **same code** will run on a single machine as well as on a cluster of machines. For more advantages of Ray see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python/48177988#48177988).

**Note:** One point to keep in mind is that each remote function is executed in a separate process, possibly on a different machine, and thus the remote function's computation should take more than invoking a remote function. As a rule of thumb a remote function's computation should take at least a few 10s of msec to amortize the scheduling and startup overhead of a remote function.

Answer (score 4):

I've always used [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) but it's not a complete analog since I believe it typically uses separate processes which can be expensive on certain operating systems. Still, if the body of your loops are chunky enough then this won't matter and can actually have some benefits.

Comment: Separate processes is also the default behavior of Matlab's `parfor`. [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html) explains how to get threads instead, but warns that functionality is limited. [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/examples/scale-up-from-desktop-to-cluster.html) mentions that `local` process-based parallelism is the default.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all solutions here, but found that the simplest way and closest equivalent to matlabs parfor is [numba's](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/prange.html) prange.

Essentially you change a single letter in your loop, range to prange:

```
from numba import autojit, prange

@autojit
def parallel_sum(A):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        sum += A[i]

    return sum
```

Comment: this only speeds up if the computation is entirely supported by numba, see docs for [list](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying joblib Parallel.

### one liner

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
out = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(heavymethod)(i) for i in range(10))
```

---

### instructional

instead of taking a for loop

```
from time import sleep
for _ in range(10):
   sleep(.2)
```

rewrite your operation into a list comprehension

```
[sleep(.2) for _ in range(10)]
```

Now let us not directly evaluate the expression, but collect what should be done.
This is what the `delayed` method is for.

```
from joblib import delayed
[delayed(sleep(.2)) for _ in range(10)]
```

Next instantiate a parallel process with n_workers and process the list.

```
from joblib import Parallel
r = Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=10)(delayed(sleep)(.2) for _ in range(10))
```

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:    0.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done   4 tasks      | elapsed:    0.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    1.4s finished
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll also give it a go, let's see if my way is easier

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
def heavy_func(key):
    #do some heavy computation on each key 
    output = key**2
    return key, output 

output_data ={}     #<--this dict will store the results
keys = [1,5,7,8,10] #<--compute heavy_func over all the values of keys
with Pool(processes=40) as pool:
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(heavy_func, keys):
        output_data[i[0]] = i[1]
```

Now output_data is a dictionary that will contain for every key the result of the computation on this key.

That is it..

Comment: I like this as it is very useful for practical use. It would be really helpful maybe to replace `i` with something more explicit, and if you explained why the use of `imap_unordered()` instead of `imap()` or `map()`.