# How to do parallel programming in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

For C++, we can use OpenMP to do parallel programming; however, OpenMP will not work for Python. What should I do if I want to parallel some parts of my python program?

The structure of the code may be considered as:

```
solve1(A)
solve2(B)
```

Where `solve1` and `solve2` are two independent function. How to run this kind of code in parallel instead of in sequence in order to reduce the running time?
The code is:

```
def solve(Q, G, n):
    i = 0
    tol = 10 ** -4

    while i < 1000:
        inneropt, partition, x = setinner(Q, G, n)
        outeropt = setouter(Q, G, n)

        if (outeropt - inneropt) / (1 + abs(outeropt) + abs(inneropt)) < tol:
            break
            
        node1 = partition[0]
        node2 = partition[1]
    
        G = updateGraph(G, node1, node2)

        if i == 999:
            print "Maximum iteration reaches"
    print inneropt
```

Where `setinner` and `setouter` are two independent functions. That's where I want to parallel...

Comment: Take a look at [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/multiprocessing.html). Note: Python's threads are not suitable for CPU-bound tasks, only for I/O-bound.

Comment: @9000 +100 internets for mentioning the CPU vs I/O dependent tasks.

Comment: @9000 Actually threads are not suitable at all for CPU-bound task as far as I know! Processes is the way to go when doing real CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: @OmarIthawi: why, threads work fine if you have many CPU cores (as usual now). Then your process can run several threads loading all these cores in parallel _and_ sharing common data between them implicitly (that is, without having an explicit shared memory area or inter-process messaging).

Comment: @9000 >>threads work fine if you have many CPU cores (as usual now). Then your process can run several threads loading all these cores in parallel and sharing common data between them implicitly<< Are you sure about this ? Becuase I read something regarding GIL here http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/multicore_python.html Where I understood exactly opposite to what you said !

Comment: @user2134774: Well, yes, my second comment makes little sense. Probably the only C extensions that release the GIL can benefit from that; e.g. parts of NumPy and Pandas do that. On other cases, it is wrong (but I cannot edit it now).

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You can use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. For this case I might use a processing pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool()
result1 = pool.apply_async(solve1, [A])    # evaluate "solve1(A)" asynchronously
result2 = pool.apply_async(solve2, [B])    # evaluate "solve2(B)" asynchronously
answer1 = result1.get(timeout=10)
answer2 = result2.get(timeout=10)
```

This will spawn processes that can do generic work for you. Since we did not pass `processes`, it will spawn one process for each CPU core on your machine. Each CPU core can execute one process simultaneously.

If you want to map a list to a single function you would do this:

```
args = [A, B]
results = pool.map(solve1, args)
```

Don't use threads because the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) locks any operations on python objects.

Comment: does `pool.map` also accepts dictionaries as args? Or only simple lists?

Comment: Just lists I think. But you can just pass in dict.items() which will be a list of key value tuples

Comment: Unfortunately this ends in an ` unhashable type: 'list'` error

Comment: in addition to my last comment: ` dict.items()` work. The error raises, because I had to change the handling of the variable insight the process-funktion. Unfortunately the error-message was not very helpful... So: thank you for your hint. :-)

Comment: What is timeout here?

Comment: Python `dict`s are not ordered. However, you could use `OrderedDict` probably.

Comment: Any idea how I can use this with websockets?

Comment: @gamma timeout is maximum time to wait for a result. If it takes longer than 10s, it is essentially aborted. This prevents waiting for crashed processes forever.

Answer (score 59):

This can be done very elegantly with [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray).

To parallelize your example, you'd need to define your functions with the `@ray.remote` decorator, and then invoke them with `.remote`.

```py
import ray

ray.init()

# Define the functions.

@ray.remote
def solve1(a):
    return 1

@ray.remote
def solve2(b):
    return 2

# Start two tasks in the background.
x_id = solve1.remote(0)
y_id = solve2.remote(1)

# Block until the tasks are done and get the results.
x, y = ray.get([x_id, y_id])
```

There are a number of advantages of this over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

1. The same code will run on a multicore machine as well as a cluster of machines.
2. Processes share data efficiently through [shared memory and zero-copy serialization](https://ray-project.github.io/2017/10/15/fast-python-serialization-with-ray-and-arrow.html).
3. Error messages are propagated nicely.
4. These function calls can be composed together, e.g.,

   ```py
   @ray.remote
   def f(x):
       return x + 1

   x_id = f.remote(1)
   y_id = f.remote(x_id)
   z_id = f.remote(y_id)
   ray.get(z_id)  # returns 4
   ```
5. In addition to invoking functions remotely, classes can be instantiated remotely as [actors](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html).

Note that [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) is a framework I've been helping develop.

Comment: i keep getting an error that says" Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ray" when trying to install the package in python

Comment: Usually this kind of error means that you need to upgrade `pip`. I'd suggest trying `pip install --upgrade pip`.

If you need to use `sudo` at all then it's possible that the version of `pip` that you're using to install `ray` is not the same one that is getting upgraded. You can check with `pip --version`.

Also, Windows is currently not supported so if you're on Windows that is probably the problem.

Comment: Just a note this is primarily for distributing concurrent jobs over multiple machines.

Comment: It actually is optimized for both the single-machine case and the cluster setting. A lot of the design decisions (e.g., shared memory, zero-copy serialization) are targeted at supporting single machines well.

Comment: It would be great if the docs pointed that out more.  I got the sense from reading over the docs that it was not really intended for the single machine case.

Comment: x_id = learner.train.remote()
it is giving an error.. it is strange since learner.train() does not have any result. 
```
 File "/home/ats4i/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 123, in compute_collision_identifier
    return hashlib.sha1(collision_identifier.encode("ascii")).digest()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 14720: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: @RobertNishihara Can you pls help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486183/how-to-run-ray-correctly? Thx.

Comment: Regarding Windows support, Ray now has initial support for Windows (still alpha).

Answer (score 7):

The solution, as others have said, is to use multiple processes. Which framework is more appropriate, however, depends on many factors. In addition to the ones already mentioned, there is also [charm4py](https://github.com/UIUC-PPL/charm4py) and [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (I am the developer of charm4py).

There is a more efficient way to implement the above example than using the worker pool abstraction. The main loop sends the same parameters (including the complete graph `G`) over and over to workers in each of the 1000 iterations. Since at least one worker will reside on a different process, this involves copying and sending the arguments to the other process(es). This could be very costly depending on the size of the objects. Instead, it makes sense to have workers store state and simply send the updated information.

For example, in charm4py this can be done like this:

```
class Worker(Chare):

    def __init__(self, Q, G, n):
        self.G = G
        ...

    def setinner(self, node1, node2):
        self.updateGraph(node1, node2)
        ...


def solve(Q, G, n):
    # create 2 workers, each on a different process, passing the initial state
    worker_a = Chare(Worker, onPE=0, args=[Q, G, n])
    worker_b = Chare(Worker, onPE=1, args=[Q, G, n])
    while i < 1000:
        result_a = worker_a.setinner(node1, node2, ret=True)  # execute setinner on worker A
        result_b = worker_b.setouter(node1, node2, ret=True)  # execute setouter on worker B

        inneropt, partition, x = result_a.get()  # wait for result from worker A
        outeropt = result_b.get()  # wait for result from worker B
        ...
```

Note that for this example we really only need one worker. The main loop could execute one of the functions, and have the worker execute the other. But my code helps to illustrate a couple of things:

1. Worker A runs in process 0 (same as the main loop). While `result_a.get()` is blocked waiting on the result, worker A does the computation in the same process.
2. Arguments are automatically passed by reference to worker A, since it is in the same
   process (there is no copying involved).

Answer (score 6):

CPython uses the Global Interpreter Lock which makes parallel programing a bit more interesting than C++

This topic has several useful examples and descriptions of the challenge:

[Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) workaround on multi-core systems using taskset on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990102/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-workaround-on-multi-core-systems-using-task)

Comment: You call the unability to _really_ run code concurrently "interesting"? :-/

Answer (score 6):

You can use `joblib` library to do parallel computation and multiprocessing.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

You can simply create a function `foo` which you want to be run in parallel and based on the following piece of code implement parallel processing:

```
output = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(foo)(i) for i in input)
```

Where `num_cores` can be obtained from `multiprocessing` library as followed:

```
import multiprocessing

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

If you have a function with more than one input argument, and you just want to iterate over one of the arguments by a list, you can use the the `partial` function from `functools` library as follow:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    '''
    body of the function
    '''
    return output
input = [11,32,44,55,23,0,100,...] # arbitrary list
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
foo_ = partial(foo, arg2=arg2, arg3=arg3, arg4=arg4)
# arg1 is being fetched from input list
output = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(foo_)(i) for i in input)
```

You can find a complete explanation of the python and R multiprocessing with couple of examples [here](https://medium.com/@najari.vahab/parallel-computing-in-r-and-python-1c916a2803d7).

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, it's possible to automatically parallelize loops using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html), though it only works with a small subset of Python:

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def prange_test(A):
    s = 0
    # Without "parallel=True" in the jit-decorator
    # the prange statement is equivalent to range
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[i]
    return s
```

Unfortunately, it seems that Numba only works with Numpy arrays, but not with other Python objects. In theory, it might also be possible to [compile Python to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650243/convert-python-program-to-c-c-code) and then [automatically parallelize it using the Intel C++ compiler](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiuucmL8oflAhURna0KHcCKCrIQFjABegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.intel.com%2Fen-us%2Fcpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-automatic-parallelization&usg=AOvVaw0tMzwSvV4bIh7nPa0q2O1s), though I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 4):

I always use the 'multiprocessing' native library to handle parallelism in Python. To control the number of processes in the queue, I use a shared variable as a counter. In the following example, you can see how the parallel execution of simple processes works.

I made an update to the script to make it easier to use. Basically, the only thing you have to do is override the `process` method with the function you want to run in parallel. See the example, the procedure is very simple. Alternatively, you can also remove all execution log occurrences.

When I have some time, I'll update the code to work with processes that return values.

### Requirements

```
user@host:~$ pip install coloredlogs==15.0.1
```

### Code

Parallel processing script **(copy and paste)**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Value, cpu_count
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from typing import Any, Iterator
from datetime import datetime
from logging import Logger
import coloredlogs
import logging
import time
import sys
import os


LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG"


def get_logger(name: str = __name__, level: str = LOG_LEVEL) -> Logger:
    assert level in ("NOTSET", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRITICAL")

    # Setting-up the script logging:
    logging.basicConfig(
        stream=sys.stdout,
        format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        level=level
    )

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    coloredlogs.install(level=level, logger=logger, isatty=True)

    return logger


class ParallelProcessing:
    """
    Parallel processing.

    References
    ----------
    [1] Class `ParallelProcessing`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464369/16109419

    Examples
    --------
    >>> class MyParallelProcessing(ParallelProcessing):
    >>>     def process(self, name: str) -> None:
    >>>         logger = get_logger()
    >>>         logger.info(f"Executing process: {name}...")
    >>>         time.sleep(5)
    >>>
    >>>
    >>> params_list = [("A",), ("B",), ("C",), ("D",), ("E",), ("F",)]
    >>> mpp = MyParallelProcessing()
    >>> mpp.run(args_list=params_list)
    """

    _n_jobs: int
    _waiting_time: int
    _queue: Value
    _logger: Logger

    def __init__(self, n_jobs: int = -1, waiting_time: int = 1):
        """
        Instantiates a parallel processing object to execute processes in parallel.

        Parameters
        ----------
        n_jobs: int
            Number of jobs.
        waiting_time: int
            Waiting time when jobs queue is full, e.g. `_queue.value` == `_n_jobs`.
        """
        self._n_jobs = n_jobs if n_jobs >= 0 else cpu_count()
        self._waiting_time = waiting_time if waiting_time >= 0 else 60*60
        self._logger = get_logger()

    def process(self, *args) -> None:
        """
        Abstract process that must be overridden.

        Parameters
        ----------
        *args
            Parameters of the process to be executed.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError("Process not defined ('NotImplementedError' exception).")

    def _execute(self, *args) -> None:
        """
        Run the process and remove it from the process queue by decreasing the queue process counter.

        Parameters
        ----------
        *args
            Parameters of the process to be executed.
        """
        self.process(*args)
        self._queue.value -= 1

    def _error_callback(self, result: Any) -> None:
        """
        Error callback.

        Parameters
        ----------
        result: Any
            Result from exceptions.
        """
        self._logger.error(result)
        os._exit(1)

    def run(self, args_list: Iterator[tuple], use_multithreading: bool = False) -> None:
        """
        Run processes in parallel.

        Parameters
        ----------
        args_list: Iterator[tuple]
            List of process parameters (`*args`).
        use_multithreading: bool
            Use multithreading instead multiprocessing.
        """
        manager = Manager()
        self._queue = manager.Value('i', 0)
        lock = manager.Lock()
        pool = Pool(processes=self._n_jobs) if not use_multithreading else ThreadPool(processes=self._n_jobs)

        start_time = datetime.now()

        with lock:  # Write-protecting the processes queue shared variable.
            for args in args_list:
                while True:
                    if self._queue.value < self._n_jobs:
                        self._queue.value += 1

                        # Running processes in parallel:
                        pool.apply_async(func=self._execute, args=args, error_callback=self._error_callback)

                        break
                    else:
                        self._logger.debug(f"Pool full ({self._n_jobs}): waiting {self._waiting_time} seconds...")
                        time.sleep(self._waiting_time)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        exec_time = datetime.now() - start_time
        self._logger.info(f"Execution time: {exec_time}")
```

Example of use:

```
class MyParallelProcessing(ParallelProcessing):
    def process(self, name: str) -> None:
        """
        Process to run in parallel (overrides abstract method).
        """
        logger = get_logger()
        logger.info(f"Executing process: {name}...")
        time.sleep(5)


def main() -> None:
    n_jobs = int(sys.argv[1])  # Number of jobs to run in parallel.
    params_list = [("A",), ("B",), ("C",), ("D",), ("E",), ("F",)]

    mpp = MyParallelProcessing(n_jobs=n_jobs)

    # Executing processes in parallel:
    mpp.run(args_list=params_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Execution and Output

```
user@host:~$ python run.py 1
2021-12-23 12:41:51 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:51 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[12352] INFO Executing process: A...
2021-12-23 12:41:52 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:53 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:54 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:55 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:56 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:57 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:57 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[12352] INFO Executing process: B...
2021-12-23 12:41:58 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:41:59 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:00 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
...
2021-12-23 12:42:10 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:11 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:12 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:12 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[12352] INFO Executing process: E...
2021-12-23 12:42:13 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:14 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:15 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:16 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] DEBUG Pool full (1): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:42:18 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[12352] INFO Executing process: F...
2021-12-23 12:42:23 MYMACHINE __main__[24180] INFO Execution time: 0:00:31.274478
```

```
user@host:~$ python run.py 3
2021-12-23 12:33:59 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:33:59 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[19776] INFO Executing process: A...
2021-12-23 12:33:59 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[24632] INFO Executing process: B...
2021-12-23 12:33:59 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[15852] INFO Executing process: C...
2021-12-23 12:34:00 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:34:01 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:34:02 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:34:03 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:34:04 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] DEBUG Pool full (3): waiting 1 seconds...
2021-12-23 12:34:05 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[19776] INFO Executing process: D...
2021-12-23 12:34:05 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[24632] INFO Executing process: E...
2021-12-23 12:34:05 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[15852] INFO Executing process: F...
2021-12-23 12:34:10 MYMACHINE __main__[7628] INFO Execution time: 0:00:11.087672
```

```
user@host:~$ python run.py 6
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[26312] INFO Executing process: A...
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[11468] INFO Executing process: B...
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[12000] INFO Executing process: C...
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[19864] INFO Executing process: D...
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[25356] INFO Executing process: E...
2021-12-23 12:40:48 MYMACHINE __mp_main__[14504] INFO Executing process: F...
2021-12-23 12:40:53 MYMACHINE __main__[1180] INFO Execution time: 0:00:05.295934
```

Comment: Excellent post on Manager

Answer (score 2):

The following may suit you if you cannot invest the time to learn the requirements and assumptions of the libraries or modules recommended in the other answers:

1. Give your script options to run individual parts of the task.
2. When ready to run `n` parts in parallel, launch them with `child = subprocess.Popen(args = [sys.argv[0], ...])`, providing the part number and other details in additional options and/or parameter files, and call `child.wait()` for each child.

If you want to monitor progress, launch more workers as soon as workers finish or do something else while waiting, use `child.poll()` instead of `child.wait()` and check whether `child.returncode` is still `None`.

For big tasks, the overhead of launching new processes and writing and reading files is minimal. For many small tasks one would want to launch workers only once and then communicate with them via pipes or sockets but that's a lot more work and and has to be done carefully to avoid the possibility of deadlocks. In this situation, it is probably better to learn how to use the modules recommended in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example that works on Windows environment; the advantage of asynchronous processing is to save time:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f1(a):
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, 99999999):
        c = c + 1
    return 1


def f2(b):
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, 99999999):
        c = c + 1
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    result1 = pool.apply_async(f1, [0])
    result2 = pool.apply_async(f2, [9])
    freeze_support()
    t0 = time.time()
    answer1 = result1.get(timeout=10)
    answer2 = result2.get(timeout=10)
    print(time.time()-t0)
    t0 = time.time()
    aa = f1(1)
    bb = f2(2)
    print(time.time()-t0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Dataframe to [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) Dataframe and It can handle the parallel computing for you.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
pdf = pd.Pandas({"A" : A, "B" : B})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=3)
solve(ddf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do parallel programming in python using threads. You must use multiprocessing, or if you do things like files or internet packets then you can use `async`, `await`, and `asyncio`.

If you want threads, you can try to use `cython` but you must install Visual Studio with python and have the developer pack installed too.