# Python: How to run nested parallel process in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a dataset `df` of trader transactions.
I have 2 levels of for loops as follows:

```
smartTrader =[]

for asset in range(len(Assets)):
    df = df[df['Assets'] == asset]
    # I have some more calculations here
    for trader in range(len(df['TraderID'])):
        # I have some calculations here, If trader is successful, I add his ID  
        # to the list as follows
        smartTrader.append(df['TraderID'][trader])

    # some more calculations here which are related to the first for loop.
```

I would like to parallelise the calculations for each asset in `Assets`, and I also want to parallelise the calculations for each trader for every asset. After ALL these calculations are done, I want to do additional analysis based on the list of `smartTrader`.

This is my first attempt at parallel processing, so please be patient with me, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Comment: I am not sure how to call this function when I have nested for loops, can you provide me with a small example please?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `pathos`, which provides a fork of `multiprocessing`, you can easily nest parallel maps. `pathos` is built for easily testing combinations of nested parallel maps -- which are direct translations of nested for loops.
It provides a selection of maps that are blocking, non-blocking, iterative, asynchronous, serial, parallel, and distributed.

```
>>> from pathos.pools import ProcessPool, ThreadPool
>>> amap = ProcessPool().amap
>>> tmap = ThreadPool().map
>>> from math import sin, cos
>>> print amap(tmap, [sin,cos], [range(10),range(10)]).get()
[[0.0, 0.8414709848078965, 0.9092974268256817, 0.1411200080598672, -0.7568024953079282, -0.9589242746631385, -0.27941549819892586, 0.6569865987187891, 0.9893582466233818, 0.4121184852417566], [1.0, 0.5403023058681398, -0.4161468365471424, -0.9899924966004454, -0.6536436208636119, 0.2836621854632263, 0.9601702866503661, 0.7539022543433046, -0.14550003380861354, -0.9111302618846769]]
```

Here this example uses a processing pool and a thread pool, where the thread map call is blocking, while the processing map call is asynchronous (note the `get` at the end of the last line).

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation
or with:

`$ pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos.git@master`

Answer (score 3):

Nested parallelism can be done elegantly with [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray), a system that allows you to easily parallelize and distribute your Python code.

Assume you want to parallelize the following nested program

```
def inner_calculation(asset, trader):
    return trader

def outer_calculation(asset):
    return  asset, [inner_calculation(asset, trader) for trader in range(5)]

inner_results = []
outer_results = []

for asset in range(10):
    outer_result, inner_result = outer_calculation(asset)
    outer_results.append(outer_result)
    inner_results.append(inner_result)

# Then you can filter inner_results to get the final output.
```

Bellow is the Ray code parallelizing the above code:

- Use the `@ray.remote decorator` for each function that we want to execute concurrently in its own process. A remote function returns a future (i.e., an identifier to the result) rather than the result itself.
- When invoking a remote function `f()` the `remote` modifier, i.e., `f.remote()`
- Use the `ids_to_vals()` helper function to convert a nested list of ids to values.

Note the program structure is identical. You only need to add `remote` and then convert the futures (ids) returned by the remote functions to values using the `ids_to_vals()` helper function.

```
import ray

ray.init()

# Define inner calculation as a remote function.
@ray.remote
def inner_calculation(asset, trader):
    return trader

# Define outer calculation to be executed as a remote function.
@ray.remote(num_return_vals = 2)
def outer_calculation(asset):
    return  asset, [inner_calculation.remote(asset, trader) for trader in range(5)]

# Helper to convert a nested list of object ids to a nested list of corresponding objects.
def ids_to_vals(ids):
    if isinstance(ids, ray.ObjectID):
        ids = ray.get(ids)
    if isinstance(ids, ray.ObjectID):
        return ids_to_vals(ids)
    if isinstance(ids, list):
        results = []
        for id in ids:
            results.append(ids_to_vals(id))
        return results
    return ids

outer_result_ids = []
inner_result_ids = []

for asset in range(10):
    outer_result_id, inner_result_id = outer_calculation.remote(asset)
    outer_result_ids.append(outer_result_id)
    inner_result_ids.append(inner_result_id)

outer_results = ids_to_vals(outer_result_ids)
inner_results = ids_to_vals(inner_result_ids)
```

There are a number of advantages of using Ray over the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. In particular, the **same code** will run on a single machine as well as on a cluster of machines. For more advantages of Ray see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python/48177988#48177988).

Comment: Why is `asset` an argument of `inner_calculation`? If I remove that argument, I get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Probably threading, from standard python library, is most convenient approach:

```
import threading

def worker(id):
    #Do you calculations here
    return

threads = []
for asset in range(len(Assets)):
    df = df[df['Assets'] == asset]
    for trader in range(len(df['TraderID'])):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(trader,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    #add semaphore here if you need synchronize results for all traders.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `for`, use `map`:

```
import functools
smartTrader =[]

m=map( calculations_as_a_function, 
        [df[df['Assets'] == asset] \
                for asset in range(len(Assets))])
functools.reduce(smartTradder.append, m)
```

From then on, you can try different parallel `map` implementations s.a. [`multiprocessing`'s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction), or [`stackless`'](http://www.grant-olson.net/files/why_stackless.html#tasklets)