# Is there parallel programming on python?

Tags: python

Today I want to program a karaoke in python.
I have to show a text (the lyrics of the song) scroll down and play the music in the background.
But I'm wondering if I have to do some code to move the lyrics and another code to play the music or I have to join both codes to do the parallel programming
But I know that Python is a structured language and I can not do parallel programming.

Comment: While paradigm (structured, OOP, functional and the likes) is not closely related to parallel programming/the lack of it anyway, in fact you will not need 'classic' parallel processing, as the caption has to stay in sync with the music. You may want to check if there is a music player API which produces you fine grained progress events and step your text/marking/whatever in the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two simple ways to do concurrent programming in Python, using build-in libraries:

1. Using the `threading` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)
2. Using the `multiprocessing` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check [Parallel Processing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing), where you can find information for:

1. Symmetric Multiprocessing
2. Cluster Computing
3. Cloud Computing
4. Grid Computing

and pick what best fits your application.

Or, check [How to do parallel programming in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python)?