# Is there a faster way to separate duplicate and different data from CSV using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe contains millions data. Suppose this is the dataframe named `mydataframe`:

```
filename | #insert-1 | #insert-2 | #delete-1 | #delete-2
---------------------------------------------------------
A        |         4 |         4 |         3 |         3
B        |         3 |         5 |         2 |         2
C        |         5 |         5 |         6 |         7
D        |         2 |         2 |         3 |         3
E        |         4 |         5 |         5 |         3
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to separate the file based on the different number of insert or delete, then save them into new `CSV` file, named `different.csv`. And also save the rest of the data having the same number of insert and delete in the separate `CSV` file called `same.csv`. In the other words, if the file has a different number between `#insert-1` and `#insert-2`, or `#delete-1` and `#delete-2` then save it in `different.csv`, otherwise, save it in `same.csv`.

The expected result:
`different.csv`:

```
filename | #insert-1 | #insert-2 | #delete-1 | #delete-2
---------------------------------------------------------
B        |         3 |         5 |         2 |         2
C        |         5 |         5 |         6 |         7
E        |         4 |         5 |         5 |         3
---------------------------------------------------------
```

`same.csv`

```
filename | #insert-1 | #insert-2 | #delete-1 | #delete-2
---------------------------------------------------------
A        |         4 |         4 |         3 |         3
D        |         2 |         2 |         3 |         3
---------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my code so far:

```
df_different = []
df_same = []
for row in range(0, len(mydataframe)):
    ins_1 = mydataframe.iloc[row][1]
    ins_2 = mydataframe.iloc[row][2]
    del_1 = mydataframe.iloc[row][3]
    del_2 = mydataframe.iloc[row][4]
    if (ins_1 != ins_2) or (del_1 != del_2):
        df_different.append(mydataframe.iloc[row])
    else:
        df_same.append(mydataframe.iloc[row])

with open('different.csv','w') as diffcsv:
    writers = csv.writer(diffcsv, delimiter=',')
    writers.writerow(fields)
    for item in df_different:
        writers.writerow(item)

with open('same.csv','w') as diffcsv:
    writers = csv.writer(diffcsv, delimiter=',')
    writers.writerow(fields)
    for item in df_same:
        writers.writerow(item)
```

Actually, the code works well but when the dataset is very large (I have millions of data), it takes very long time (more than 3 hours) to perform. My question is whether there is a method to make it faster. Thank you.

Comment: for me this sounds like it could be parallised easily. just split your dataframe.
more for parallisation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python, but yeah the answer of DSM is what your searching for i guess

Comment: Would be good to see timings on the actual data. @Yusuf - would you be so kind as to time the solutions provided below to demonstrate the gains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid iterating over rows; that's pretty slow.  Instead, vectorize the comparison operation:

```
same_mask = (df["#insert-1"] == df["#insert-2"]) & (df["#delete-1"] == df["#delete-2"])
df.loc[same_mask].to_csv("same.csv", index=False)
df.loc[~same_mask].to_csv("different.csv", index=False)
```

For a dataframe of 1M rows, this takes me only a few seconds.

Comment: It saved my time significantly. For more than 3 hours using my own code, it reduced to only no more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easy things you can do is to provide sufficiently large buffers to `open` function (`buffering=64*1024*1024`) could help (64MB buffer).

Another thing is iteration over the dataframe - instead of iterating over row numbers you could [iterate directly over rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas), like:

```
for index, row in mydataframe.iterrows():
    ins_1 = row[1]
    ins_2 = row[2]
    del_1 = row[3]
    del_2 = row[4]
```

I would expect it to be much faster.

Comment: if you have only 4 elements you can do `ins_1,ins_2,del_1,del_2 = row`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You are right. This should be even faster!

Answer (score 2):

Use directly Data Frame query:

Same_data frame:

```
same_dataframe = mydataframe[(mydataframe["insert1"] == mydataframe["insert2"]) & (mydataframe["delete1"] == mydataframe["delete2"])]
```

Different Dataframe:

```
different_data = mydataframe[(mydataframe["insert1"] != mydataframe["insert2"]) | (mydataframe["delete1"] != mydataframe["delete2"])]
```

I think, it is faster than iteration.

Hope, It will help.