# Calculating a for loop with different indexes simultaneosuly

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following for function:

```
def calculateEMAs(df,startIndex,endIndex):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        for i in range (1,51):
            if(index-i > 0):
              df.loc[index,"EMA%d"%i] = abs(df.iloc[index-i]["Trade Close"] - df.iloc[index]["Trade Close"])/2 #replace this with EMA formula
    print(df)
```

This for loop takes a long time to calculate the values for the data frame as it has to loop 50 times for each row (it takes approximately 62 seconds)

I tried to use multiprocessor pool from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python) question. My code looks like this now:

```
def calculateEMAs(df,startIndex,endIndex):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        for i in range (startIndex,endIndex):
            if(index-i > 0):
              df.loc[index,"EMA%d"%i] = abs(df.iloc[index-i]["Trade Close"] - df.iloc[index]["Trade Close"])/2 #replace this with EMA formula
    print(df)
  
def main():
    dfClosePrice= getFileDataframe().to_frame()
    pool = Pool()
    time0 = time.time()
    result1 = pool.apply_async(calculateEMAs,[dfClosePrice,1,10])
    result2 = pool.apply_async(calculateEMAs,[dfClosePrice,10,20])
    result3 = pool.apply_async(calculateEMAs,[dfClosePrice,20,30])
    result4 = pool.apply_async(calculateEMAs,[dfClosePrice,30,40])
    result5 = pool.apply_async(calculateEMAs,[dfClosePrice,40,51])
    answer1 = result1.get()
    answer2 = result2.get()
    answer3 = result3.get()
    answer4 = result4.get()
    answer5 = result5.get()
    print(time.time() - time0)
    print(dfClosePrice)
```

I run the function asynchronously with different values for the for loop. this takes 19 seconds to complete and I can see the result of each function printed correctly but the final value of `dfClosePirce` is a dataframe with only 1 column (Trade Close) and the new columns from each async function will not be added to the dataframe. How can I do it the right way?

Comment: Each process has its own independent copy of the dataframe, that was passed to it as a parameter.  Any changes that they make to their dataframe aren't going to magically be transferred back to the main process, you have to explicitly return the updated dataframes, and merge them back together.

Comment: Have you tried alternative looping methods to iterrows in your original solution?  I ask since iterrows is one of the slowest options for looping over a DataFrame i.e. [Why Pandas itertuples() Is Faster Than iterrows() and How To Make It Even Faster](https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d).

Comment: @DarrylG I didn't know the problem might be iterrows. I will checkout itertuples()

Comment: @Morez--seems this can be done in a few milliseconds.  I'll post a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Using Numpy vectorization

*Issue*

1. Line `if(index-i > 0):` should be `if(index-i >= 0):` otherwise we miss the difference of 1
2. Use 'Close' rather than 'Trade Close' (doesn't matter for performance but avoid renaming column after pulling data from web)

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def compute_using_np(df, start_index, end_index):
    '''
        Using numpy to vectorize computation
    '''
    nrows = len(df)                         
    ncols = end_index - start_index

    # container for pairwise differences
    pair_wise_diff = np.empty((nrows, ncols))  #np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype = float)
    pair_wise_diff.fill(np.nan)
    # Get values of Trading close column as numpy 1D array
    values = df['Close'].values

    # Compute differences for different offsets
    for offset in range(startIndex, endIndex):
        # Using numpy to compute vectorized difference (i.e. faster computation)
        diff = np.abs(values[offset:] - values[:-offset])/2.0
                              
        # Update result
        pair_wise_diff[offset:, offset-startIndex] = diff
                              
    # Place into DataFrame
    columns = ["EMA%d"%i for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
                              
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(data = pair_wise_diff, index = np.arange(nrows), columns = columns)
            
    # Add result to df merging on index
    return df.join(df_result)
```

**Usage**

```
df_result = compute_using_np(df, 1, 51)
```

**Performance**

*Summary*

- Posted Code: 37.9 s ± 143 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- Numpy Code:  1.56 ms ± 27.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- Result: 20K times speed up

*Test Code*

```
import pandas_datareader as dr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculateEMAs(df, start_index, end_index):
    '''
       Posted code changed 1) use Python PEP 8 naming convention, 
                           2) corrected conditional
    '''
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        for i in range (start_index, end_index):
            if(index-i >= 0):
              df.loc[index,"EMA%d"%i] = abs(df.iloc[index-i]["Close"] - df.iloc[index]["Close"])/2 #replace this with EMA formula
    return df

def compute_using_np(df, start_index, end_index):
    '''
        Using numpy to vectorie computation
    '''
    nrows = len(df)                         
    
    ncols = end_index - start_index

    # container for pairwise differences
    pair_wise_diff = np.empty((nrows, ncols))  #np.zeros((nrows, ncols), dtype = float)
    pair_wise_diff.fill(np.nan)
    # Get values of Trading close column as numpy 1D array
    values = df['Close'].values

    # Compute differences for different offsets
    for offset in range(start_index, end_index):
        # Using numpy to compute vectorized difference (i.e. faster computation)
        diff = np.abs(values[offset:] - values[:-offset])/2.0
                              
        # Update result
        pair_wise_diff[offset:, offset-start_index] = diff
                              
    # Place into DataFrame
    columns = ["EMA%d"%i for i in range(start_index, end_index)]
                              
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(data = pair_wise_diff, index = np.arange(nrows), columns = columns)
            
    # Add result to df merging on index
    return df.join(df_result)

# Get ibm closing stock pricing (777 DataFrame rows)
df = dr.data.get_data_yahoo('ibm', start = '2017-09-01', end = '2020-10-02')
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace = True)   # create index which is 0, 1, 2, ...

# Time Original post
df1 = df.copy()                    # Copy data since operation is inplace
%timeit calculateEMAs(df1, 1, 51)  # Jupyter Notebook Magic method

# Time Numpy Version
%timeit compute_using_np(df, 1, 51)  # Jupyter Notebook Magic method 
                                     # No need to copy since operation is not inplace
```

Comment: Wow it's much faster. What's the reason behind it and why is it faster than my code?

Comment: @Morez--articles such as [A Beginner’s Guide to Optimizing Pandas Code for Speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) illustrate how Pandas can be sped up with the optimum one being numpy vectorization if possible.   In this the line `diff = np.abs(values[offset:] - values[:-offset])/2.0` use numpy vectorization to compute the difference for a given offset which is much faster than doing it with a Python for loop.

Comment: @Morez--in case that answer was hard to read, just think of Numpy and Pandas libraries being C-code whose functions run much faster than pure Python (i.e., Python interpreter). So for developing algorithms you want to use whatever lets you code quickly try out ideas then refactor using Numpy/Pandas if speed is required (for Data Science applications).