# Parallelizing Python code on Azure Databricks

Tags: python, multiprocessing, rdd, azure-databricks, hyperparameters

I'm trying to port over some "parallel" Python code to Azure Databricks. The code runs perfectly fine locally, but somehow doesn't on Azure Databricks. The code leverages the `multiprocessing` library, and more specifically the `starmap` function.

The code goes like this:

```py
from sklearn import metrics
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np

def init_pool():
    from threading import current_thread
    ident = current_thread().ident
    np.random.seed(ident)

def train_model(params, Xt, yt, Xv, yv):
    model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary', subsample=0.8, random_state=123, **params)
    model.fit(Xt, yt)
    proba = model.predict_proba(Xv)[:, 1]
    return metrics.roc_auc_score(yv, proba)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from itertools import product, repeat
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from time import time
    import pandas as pd
    
    def generate_data(n):
        '''Generates random data'''

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            'x1': np.random.random(n) * 100,
            'x2': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], n, replace=True),
            'x3': np.random.choice(['cow', 'platypus', 'koala', 'panda', 'camel'], n, replace=True),
            'x4': np.random.poisson(15, n),
            'y': np.random.choice([0, 1], n, replace=True, p=[0.8, 0.2])
        })

        # Necessary steps for lightgbm
        for _ in df.columns:
            if df[_].dtypes == 'object':
                df[_] = df[_].astype('category')

        X, y = df.drop(['y'], axis=1), df['y']
        return train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)

    def grid_to_list(grid):
        '''Parameter grid is converted to a list of all combinations'''
        keys, values = zip(*grid.items())
        return [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in product(*values)]

    param_list = grid_to_list({
        'num_leaves': [20, 30, 40],
        'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.3],
        'n_estimators': [50, 100, 250]
    })

    n = 100_000
    Xt, Xv, yt, yv = generate_data(n=n)
    pool_size = min(mp.cpu_count(), len(param_list))

    start = time()
    p = mp.Pool(pool_size, initializer=init_pool)
    ROC = p.starmap(train_model, zip(param_list, repeat(Xt), repeat(yt), repeat(Xv), repeat(yv)))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    end = time()

    print(f"Total running time for {len(param_list)} combinations: {round(end - start, 0)} seconds.")
    print(f"Highest ROC AUC score: {np.max(ROC)}")
    print(f"Matching parameters: {param_list[np.argmax(ROC)]}")
```

Running this on my personnal laptop outputs the following:

```
Total running time for 18 combinations: 24.0 seconds.
Highest ROC AUC score: 0.5079410814800223
Matching parameters: {'num_leaves': 30, 'learning_rate': 0.3, 'n_estimators': 50}
```

So my first question is:

1. why won't it run on Azure Databricks?

Now, poking around a bit looking for alternatives, I was told about "resilient distributed datasets" or "rdd" and, after some effort, managed to have the following work:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from itertools import product, repeat
import multiprocessing as mp
from sklearn import metrics
import lightgbm as lgb
from time import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x1': np.random.random(n) * 100,
        'x2': np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], n, replace=True),
        'x3': np.random.choice(['cow', 'platypus', 'koala', 'panda', 'camel'], n, replace=True),
        'x4': np.random.poisson(15, n),
        'y': np.random.choice([0, 1], n, replace=True, p=[0.8, 0.2])
    })

    # Necessary steps for lightgbm
    for _ in df.columns:
        if df[_].dtypes == 'object':
            df[_] = df[_].astype('category')

    X, y = df.drop(['y'], axis=1), df['y']
    return train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)

n = 100_000
Xt, Xv, yt, yv = generate_data(n=n)

def grid_to_list(grid):
    '''Parameter grid is converted to a list of all combinations'''
    keys, values = zip(*grid.items())
    return [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in product(*values)]

param_list = grid_to_list({
    'num_leaves': [20, 30, 40],
    'learning_rate': [0.1, 0.3],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 250]
})

class HyperparameterOptimiser:
    def __init__(self, params, Xt, yt, Xv, yv, train_fct):
        self.param_list = params
        self.Xt = Xt
        self.yt = yt
        self.Xv = Xv
        self.yv = yv
        self.train_fct = train_fct
    
    def optimise(self, n_jobs=None):
        if n_jobs is None:
            n_jobs = min(len(self.param_list), 4 * 16) # Pourquoi 4 * 16?
    
        start = time()
        # <BEGIN ANNOYING SECTION>
        train_fct = self.train_fct
        Xt = self.Xt
        yt = self.yt
        Xv = self.Xv
        yv = self.yv
        rdd = sc.parallelize(self.param_list, n_jobs)
        self.ROC = rdd.map(lambda p: train_fct(p, Xt, yt, Xv, yv)).collect()
        # <END ANNOYING SECTION>
        self.running_time = round(time() - start, 0)
        self.output_results()
        pass
  
    def output_results(self):
        print(f"Total running time for {len(self.param_list)} combinations: {self.running_time} seconds.")
        print(f"Highest ROC AUC score: {max(self.ROC)}")
        print(f"Matching parameters: {self.param_list[np.argmax(self.ROC)]}")
        pass

def train_model(params, Xt, yt, Xv, yv):
    model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary', subsample=0.8, random_state=123, **params)
    model.fit(Xt, yt)
    predictions = model.predict_proba(Xv)[:, 1]
    return metrics.roc_auc_score(yv, predictions)

# Note: very useful to be able to pass whatever "train function" is warranted with regard to context
ho = HyperparameterOptimiser(param_list, Xt, yt, Xv, yv, train_model)
ho.optimise()
```

In this case, the running time is the following:

```
Total running time for 18 combinations: 356.0 seconds.
Highest ROC AUC score: 0.5065868367986968
Matching parameters: {'num_leaves': 20, 'learning_rate': 0.3, 'n_estimators': 100}
```

This, however, raises more questions than answers:

2. Why it is so much slower?
3. Why must I pass every argument individually (please see the "ANNOYING SECTION" in the code comments), and not through the `self` object, as I would have with the `starmap` function in the first case?

I am guessing part of the answer to question no2 has to do with my choice of cluster, relative to the specs of my personnal computer. While I agree with that, the code is far from intensive, and I find it somewhat puzzling that the difference would amount to *that* big a number.

Hopefully, this will generate discussions that'll be helpful to others as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop trying to invent the wheel, and instead start to leverage the built-in capabilities of Azure Databricks. Because Apache Spark (and Databricks) is the distributed system, machine learning on it should be also distributed. There are two approaches to that:

1. Training algorithm is implemented in the distributed fashion - [there is a number of such algorithms](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) packaged into Apache Spark and included into Databricks Runtimes
2. Use machine learning implementations designed to run on a single node, but train multiple models in parallel - that what typically happens during hyper-parameters optimization.  And what is you're trying to do

Databricks runtime for machine learning [includes the Hyperopt library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/) that is designed for the efficient finding of best hyper-parameters without trying all combinations of the parameters, that allows to find them faster.  It also include the [SparkTrials API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/machine-learning/automl-hyperparam-tuning/hyperopt-concepts#the-sparktrials-class) that is designed to parallelize computations for single-machine ML models such as scikit-learn. Documentation includes a number of examples of using that library with single-node ML algorithms, that you can use as a base for your work - for example, here is an [example for scikit-learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/hyperopt-spark-mlflow.html).

P.S. When you're running the code with multiprocessing, then the code is executed only on the driver node, and the rest of the cluster isn't utilized at all.

Comment: If not doing hyperparameter tuning then i think OP's method
`rdd = sc.parallelize(self.param_list, n_jobs)`
and
`self.ROC = rdd.map(lambda p: train_fct(p, Xt, yt, Xv, yv)).collect()`
is correct

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue in Azure Databricks and was only able to perform parallel processing based on threads instead processes. Take a look at the following post I made on the subject: ["How to do parallel programming in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70464369/16109419). The code is very simple and easy to customize. **Just copy and use!**