# Asynchronous processing in spark pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, asynchronous, distributed-computing, system-design

I have a local linux server which contains 4 cores. I am running a pyspark job on it locally which basically reads two tables from database and saves the data into 2 dataframes. Now i am using these 2 dataframes to do some processing and then i am using the resultant processed df to save it into elasticsearch. Below is the code

```
def save_to_es(df):
  
    
    df.write.format('es').option('es.nodes', 'es_node').option('es.port', some_port_no.).option('es.resource', index_name).option('es.mapping', es_mappings).save()
    
    
                   
    def coreFun():
        
        spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName('test').getOrCreate()
        
        spark.catalog.clearCache()
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        sc = spark.sparkContext
        
        sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
        
        select_sql = """(select * from db."master_table")"""
        
        
        df_master = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbcurl").option("dbtable", select_sql).option("user", "username").option("password", "password").option("driver", "database_driver").load()
      
        
        select_sql_child = """(select * from db."child_table")""" 
        
        df_child = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbcurl").option("dbtable", select_sql_cost).option("user", "username").option("password", "password").option("driver", "database_driver").load()
        
        merged_df = merged_python_file.merged_function(df_master,df_child,sqlContext)
        logic1_df = logic1_python_file.logic1_function(df_master,sqlContext)
        logic2_df = logic2_python_file.logic2_function(df_master,sqlContext)
        logic3_df = logic3_python_file.logic3_function(df_master,sqlContext)
        logic4_df = logic4_python_file.logic4_function(df_master,sqlContext)
        logic5_df = logic5_python_file.logic5_function(df_master,sqlContext)
        
        save_to_es(merged_df)
        save_to_es(logic1_df)
        save_to_es(logic2_df)
        save_to_es(logic3_df)
        save_to_es(logic4_df)
        save_to_es(logic5_df)
        
        end_time = int(time.time())
        print(end_time-start_time)
        sc.stop()
        
        
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        coreFun()
```

There are different logic for processing written in separate python files e.g logic1 in logic1_python_file etc. I send my df_master to separate functions and they return resultant processed df back to driver. Now i use this resultant processed df to save into elasticsearch.
It works fine but problem is  here everything is happening sequentially first merged_df gets processed and while it is getting processed others simply wait even though they are not really dependent on the o/p of merged_df function and then logic_1 gets processed while others wait and it goes on. This is not an ideal system design considering the o/p of one logic is not dependent on other.

I am sure asynchronous processing can help me here but i am not sure how to implement it here in my usecase. I know i may have to use some kind of queue(jms,kafka etc) to accomplish this but i dont have a complete picture.

Please let me know how can i utilize asynchronous processing here. Any other inputs which can help in improving the performance of job is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If during the processing of one single step like (merged_python_file.merged_function), only one core of the CPU is getting heavily utilized and others are nearly idle, multiprocessing can speed up. It can be achieved by using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module of python. For more details can check answer on [How to do parallel programming in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python)