# How to run parallelly the same function in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am running one code where the python script is basically scraping through a list of links.
But the process is too slow.I want to divide my code into several process where the code is simultaneously scrapping through multiple links at once.

List of Links is almost 5000.

Here is my code which I want to run in parallel

```py
#links contains list of links 
def fun():
    for link in links:
        requests.get(link,timeout=5)
        ###... scraping code
        #####
```

Comment: Use [AIOHTTP](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548628/how-to-do-parallel-programming-in-python

Comment: I have tried using multiprocessing module not working for my case

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make more requests at the same time, you don't want to use `requests`, but [`AIOHTTP`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead.

The package allows you to make `HTTP` requests asynchronously.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to use AIOHTTP in this case? (for example, it probably doesn't make much sense for them to `await` each request in a loop, nor to `asyncio.gather()` all 5000!)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of AIOHTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest build a  multithreaded program to make requests. `concurrent.futures` is one of the easiest ways to multithread these kinds of requests, in particular using the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). They even have a simple multithreaded URL request example in the documentation.

here is a sample code using `bs4` and `concurrent.futures`

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

URLs = [ ... ] # A long list of URLs.

def parse(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup.find_all('a')

# run 10 workers concurrently, it depends on the number of core/threads of your processor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    start = time.time()
    futures = [ executor.submit(parse, url) for url in URLs ]
    results = []
    for result in as_completed(futures):
        results.append(result)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time Taken: {:.6f}s".format(end-start))
```

Also, you may want to check out python [scrapy framework](https://scrapy.org/), it will scrape the data concurrently and very easy to learn, also it comes with many features such as auto-throttle, rotating proxies and user-agents, you can easily integrate with your databases as well.

Comment: while this may work, using `concurrent.futures` in general, skipping (or indeed setting) the request timeout without extra Exception handling, etc. is fraught with perils! if you've used Scrapy before, it might make a good second Answer!

Comment: I agree, for this type of use case I personally use scrapy or  similar libraries

Comment: Sorry But it doesn't works @ahmedshahriar

Comment: It still is working sequentially which makes the code run same as before

Comment: Then I suggest use scrapy @SohamChakraborty