# How to use IPython.parallel for functions with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, ipython-parallel

This is my first attempt at using `IPython.parallel` so please bear with me.

I read this question
[Parfor for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682429/parfor-for-python)
and am having trouble implementing a simple example as follows:

```
import gmpy2 as gm
import numpy as np
from IPython.parallel import Client

rc = Client()
lview = rc.load_balanced_view()
lview.block = True

a = 1
def L2(ii,jj):
    out = []
    out.append(gm.fac(ii+jj+a))
    return out 

Nloop = 100
ii = range(Nloop)
jj = range(Nloop)
R2 = lview.map(L2, zip(ii, jj))
```

The problems I have are:

1. `a` is defined outside the loop and I think I need to do something like "push" but am a bit confused by that. Do I need to "pull" after?
2. there are two arguments that are required for the function and I don't know how to pass them correctly. I tried things like `zip(ii,jj)` but got some errors.
3. Also,, I assume the fact that I'm using a random library `gmpy2` shouldn't affect things. Is this correct? Do I need to do anything special for this?

Ideally I would like your help so on this simple example the code runs error free.

If you think it would be beneficial to post my failed attempts at #2 let me know. I'm in the dark with #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways that make this work:

One is `push`ing the variable to the cores. There is no need to pull it. The variable will simply be defined in the namespace of each process-engine.

```
rc.client[:].push({'a':a})
R2 = lview.map(L2, ii, jj)
```

The other way is as to redefine `L2` to take `a` as an input and pass an array of `a`'s to the `map` function:

```
def L2(ii,jj,a):
    out = []
    out.append(gm.fac(ii+jj+a))
    return out
R2 = lview.map(L2, ii, jj, [a]*Nloop)
```

With regards to the import as per this website:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html#non-blocking-execution
You simply import the required libraries in the function:

> Note the import inside the function. This is a common model, to ensure
>   that the appropriate modules are imported where the task is run. You
>   can also manually import modules into the engine(s) namespace(s) via
>   view.execute('import numpy')().

Or you can do as per this link
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html#remote-imports